# Does N'Zoth the corruptor invoke minions in a specific order?

Tags: hearthstone

I'm wondering a point about N'Zoth. He will summon my dead deathrattle minions, but will he do it in a specific order (death order, mana cost order, ...) ? Or randomly ?

If there is already a few minions on my side of the board, I'd like to predict which minions will be summoned and which ones will not (because board is full). If it's by death order, this generally means lower cost minions (like fire bat) will be summoned before the interesting big drops (sylvanas, highmane or so).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### N'Zoth embraces chaos, so the summoning order is random!

Confirmed by Blizzard [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/PlayHearthstone/status/713055841562206208):

> @SpenserTrompke N'Zoth embraces chaos, so the resurrected Deathrattle minions will be random.